# Angular2 code gives inline template error

Tags: javascript, html, templates, angular, components

I have the following code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'character',
      template: `<h2 class="{{name}}">{{name}}</h2>
                <ul>
                     <li *ngFor="let charStat of charStats">
                       <p>Abilities = {{charStat.abilities}}</p>
                       <p>Appearance = {{chatStat.appearance}}</p>
                       <p>Equipment = {{charStat.equipment}}</p>
                       <p>Description = {{charStat.description}}</p>
                     </li>
                </ul>`
    })

    export class CharacterDetailsComponent {
      name = 'Mr Character';
      charStats = [{
        "id": 1,
        "abilities": [],
        "appearance": [],
        "equipment": [],
        "description": "I was born in a text village."
        }];
    }
```

However, when I try to run it, the template renders as a single bullet-point only and shows the following error in the browser console:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./CharacterDetailsComponent class CharacterDetailsComponent - inline template:4:26
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have a typo:

```
<p>Appearance = {{chatStat.appearance}}</p>
```

it should be `charStat`

`r` instead of `t`

Comment: Ugh! Weird that this messed up all the other fields, though. Wouldn't have expected that. Guess it's just a case of getting used to the vagaries of a new framework. Was expecting the problem to be with the first entry at the very least, given the output.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's because `<p>` is not allowed within `<li>`

The Angular2 is strict about invalid HTML.

Comment: Oh, strange. I wouldn't have done that myself, but that's the way it was in the Code School tutorial and they're usually bang on accurate, so I just trusted them that it was ok.

Comment: If @yurzui s solution fixes your issue I'm wrong anyway.

Comment: Not exactly. His solution fixed the initial problem, but yours fixed the one that came up after. I'm sure I could have found it myself, but your solution made it a lot quicker to fix. On a tangential note I really like Angular2 now I've got used to it. REALLY quick to write. Though slow as hell to load on default settings :P.